# what is difference between sinput and input?

Tags: trading, algorithmic-trading, mql4, mql5, expert-advisor

i wish you best.
what is actually difference between static input and normal input in MQL language? i mean `sinput` and `sinput`
in the book that i read written that:
**"The value of a static input variable can be changed, but it cannot be optimized in the Strategy Tester. Static input variables are useful for logical grouping of input parameters."**
what does it mean exactly "it cannot be optimazed"? could you tell me a example please?

i can't undrestand the explanation and core difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sinput` or `static input` simply excludes the variable from being able to have multiple different values tested when using the strategy tester.

You can find a more detailed explanation in the documents:

[Input Variables](https://docs.mql4.com/basis/variables/inputvariables)